# Could I say: "my left-reclining body", meaning that I'm lying down on my left side?

Tags: phrases

And if yes, would that make it good english?
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could say it, and it's probably technically valid English, but it's certainly not idiomatic.

Comment: "I reclined; listing to port."

Comment: @Oldbag That was a good one!

Answer (score 2):

"in the left-lateral position" is a bit technical, but describes perfectly that position. Or, simply, "He was lying on his left side." as you've mentioned.

- "He was lying on his left side."
- "He was lying motionless in the left-lateral position."[image]"